# Error when a new module created in Drupal 8

Tags: php, drupal, hook, drupal-8, drupal-hooks

I created a custom module in Drupal 8 and my error logs gave me the following message:

> ReflectionException: Class Drupal\onesignal_api\src\Controller\OneSignalApiController does not exist in ReflectionMethod->__construct() (line 123 of core/lib/Drupal/Core/Entity/EntityResolverManager.php)

here are my files:

**onesignal_api.routing.yml:**

```
onesignal_api:
 path: '/onesignal_api'
 defaults:
   _controller:'Drupal\onesignal_api\src\Controller\OneSignalApiController::hook_onesignal_api_insert'
_title: 'One Signal API'
requirements:
  _permission: ‘access content’
```

**OneSignalApiController.php:**

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\onesignal_api\Controller; 

class OneSignalApiController {

/***
* Hook into OneSignal API to send push notifications once a new node is created
*/


   function hook_onesignal_api_insert(Drupal\Core\Node\NodeAPI $node) {
      if($node->isNew()) {
        // Code to execute
      }
   }
}
```

What is the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the value of `_controller:`

`'Drupal\onesignal_api\src\Controller\OneSignalApiController::hook_onesignal_api_insert'`

You need to remove the `\src`.

That value should refer to the namespace, `namespace Drupal\onesignal_api\Controller;` not the path.

---

Also, maybe something just got lost in translation while posting the question here, but the indentation is off in your routing file and you have some curly quotes around `access content` that need to be replaced with straight quotes.

```
onesignal_api:
  path: '/onesignal_api'
  defaults:
    _controller: 'Drupal\onesignal_api\Controller\OneSignalApiController::hook_onesignal_api_insert'
    _title: 'One Signal API'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'access content'
```

Comment: Thanks that was it.